# Plot a a json chart with HighCharts & Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, vuejs2

I'm trying to plot some data I have in my database. I'm following [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/) for the structure. However even though I manage to get the data correctly from my API, the chart shows up but no data is plotted.

My app.js looks something like this:

```
// Load Sessions
var sessions = new Vue({
  el: '#sessions',
  delimiters: ["v{","}"],
  data: { date:'', sessions:'', json:'', timestamp:''},
  methods: {
    loadSessions: function(){
      var vm = this
      axios.get('/api/v1/metrics/')
           .then(function(response) {
             vm.json = response.data
             Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    chart: {
                        zoomType: 'x'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Session Over Time'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                                'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Sessions'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        area: {
                            fillColor: {
                                linearGradient: {
                                    x1: 0,
                                    y1: 0,
                                    x2: 0,
                                    y2: 1
                                },
                                stops: [
                                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                                ]
                            },
                            marker: {
                                radius: 2
                            },
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            },
                            threshold: null
                        }
                    },

                    series: [{
                        type: 'area',
                        name: 'Sessions',
                        data: vm.json
                    }]
                });
           })
    }
  }
})
```

The `vm.json` file looks like this:

```
[ { "date": "2017-01-02", "timestamp": 1483401600, "sessions": 1100 }, { "date": "2017-01-03", "timestamp": 1483488000, "sessions": 1159 }, { "date": "2017-01-04", "timestamp": 1483574400, "sessions": 1084 }]
```

And I load vue in my html with a simple:

```
<div id='sessions'>
<a class="button is-primary" @click='loadSessions'>Load Sessions</a>

<!-- Just to test that data is loaded correctly from API -->
<ul style="margin-left: 20px;">
  <li v-for="item in json">
    <b>Date: </b> v{item.date} <br />
    <b>Sessions:</b> v{item.sessions} <br />
    <b>Timestamp:</b> v{item.timestamp}
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</div>
```

Now I think that my problem is on formatting the json, isn't it? The on in the jsfiddle example looks a bit different. How can I get my data to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your data into the format that is shown in the example.

```
series: [{
  type: 'area',
  name: 'Sessions',
  data: vm.json.map(d => [new Date(d.date).getTime(), d.sessions])
}]
```

I converted your `date` properties to Javascript Date objects in order to use `getTime` because your `timestamp` property, where ever it came from, is not a proper Javascript timestamp.

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ybJmZz?editors=1010).

Comment: Hi, I've tried with your settings but something doesn't seem to work. If I add `vm.nex = vm.json.map(d => [new Date(d.date).getTime(), d.sessions])` just under `vm.json = response.data` and then I add `v{nex}` in my template nothing loads and also the chart doesn't load. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Costantin Does `response.data` actually have any data?

Comment: yes, because when I render `vm.json = response.data` with `v{json}` I get the following: `[ { "date": "2017-01-06", "timestamp": 1483747200, "sessions": 1180 }, { "date": "2017-01-08", "timestamp": 1483920000, "sessions": 966 }, { "date": "2017-01-09", "timestamp": 1484006400, "sessions": 1203 } etc`

Comment: @Costantin is there a console error? Does `response.data` contain a string or an actual array?

Comment: Yes, now that I've checked I get this error: `[Vue warn]: Property or method "nex" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in <Root>)`

Comment: But I did add it in my data like this: `data: { date:'', sessions:'', json:'', timestamp:'', nex:''},`